# can't display ￥ with TCPDF, but other kanji are okay

Tags: php, tcpdf, truetype

I'm using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) to create PDFs that include Japanese characters.  Using the [TrueType font ArialUni](http://www.filecrop.com/arialuni.ttf.html), most characters are displayed correctly, except the yen symbol shows up as a square box instead of ￥.

Here's a snippet of the resulting PDF using ArialUni:

[image: using ArialUni]

So I tried another font.  Here's the same section of the resulting PDF using [GT200001](http://www.l.u-tokyo.ac.jp/GT/downloads.html):

[image: using GT200001]

And here's the same section using Helvetica:

[image: using Helvetica]

Here's the same section using [GNU's FreeSans](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/):

[image: using FreeSans]

I would like that second line to show up as "(渋谷猿, ¥8,000)"

I'm not surprised that Helvetica and Freesans cannot render the kanji correctly, but I cannot fathom why the other two fonts can render the kanji, but not the yen symbol, which is much more common.

The web server creating the PDFs is LAMP running Ubuntu.  I'm viewing the PDFs on OS X with Chrome (using its in-browser view).  I've also tried downloading the PDFs with Firefox and displaying in Preview.  I get essentially the same results: ArialUni and GT200001 don't display the yen symbol, while Helvetica and Freesans don't display the kanji (but *do* display the yen symbol).

I know I can use different fonts for different lines/cells of the PDF, but the kanji and yen symbol are on the same line.

**How can I get the kanji and yen symbol to display in a single line using TCPDF?**

Near the top of my PDF code, I load the font using TCPDF's addTTFfont();

```
    $this->font = $this->addTTFfont(K_PATH_FONTS.'arialuni.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

Here's the code I'm using to write the section of the PDF.

```
        $pdf->SetFont('arialuni','',10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(105, $remarks_height, $remarks, 'B', 'L', false, 0, '', '', true, 1, false, true,  $remarks_height, 'T');
```

Comment: I think this means the ¥ is not encoded correctly...

Comment: You cannot use that because `arialuni.ttf` doesn't have it as a symbol. You can edit your font and add that symbol.

Comment: I don't know if `TCPDF` supports codes, can you try with `&#165;` ?

Comment: &#165;  comes out as "(渋谷猿,  &#165;8,000)"

I'm looking for a free font editor now.

Comment: @MihaiIorga http://www.fonts.com/font/ascender/arial-unicode lets me display ￥ with no problem in Arialuni.  Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @nneonneo do you mean within my PHP source code?  Maybe in the DB?  We're using UTF-8 everywhere; I'm not sure how else to encode it.

Comment: @ThunderRabbit So the string decodes properly with UTF-8 then? It is an interesting problem. I am almost certain a character encoding issue is occurring *somewhere*...but it could be TCPDF's fault.

Comment: @nneonneo I remember seeing a discussion online with people saying it was TCPDF, and TCPDF programmer saying it's not.  Can't seem to find that discussion now, though.  Our solution at that time was to use different fonts depending on needs, but now that won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A5) you can read some more about this character.

Basically, there are 2 different ways of writing this Japanese Kanji, as it happens with some other symbols. From accepted answer "I was using ¥, not ￥", we can see that he was using the 'occidental' or Unicode ¥ symbol, when he actually wanted to use the double-width character ￥.

Comment: I had forgotten that originally the client wanted the narrow yen symbol, but once I explained the issue, "ya get a wide symbol or a square," they went with the wide version.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Oh dear, I figured it out.

I was using ¥, not ￥.  Sorry for being confused!!

Answer (score 2):

What I have noticed with TCPDF is, it's all about fonts.
I tried to use it for 15 totally different languages with different writing style too and only font I am using is Arial UNICODE MS.

TCPDF has function which will convert that font into TCPDF friendly files, which are arialuni.ctg.z(70k), arialuni.php(447k), and arialuni.z (14M).

the functions are,
http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/ARIALUNICODE.TTF', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

Comment: Thanks for the conversion tip.  I was already using that, and even tried *not* converting to see if it would fix the problem.